# Turn html table into CSV using beautifulsoup

Tags: html, csv, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

I'm new to scraping and I can't figure out how to get the data that I need from a certain website. Here is my code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

website_url = requests.get('https://thereserve2.apx.com/mymodule/reg/prjView.asp?id1=1295').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())

table = soup.table
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Rows'] = row
df
```

The output is showing the table like `['Column 1','Column 2']` so it should be easy to turn it into a exportable table but it isn't working for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


website_url = requests.get('https://thereserve2.apx.com/mymodule/reg/prjView.asp?id1=1295').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'html.parser')
table = soup.table
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

data = {}
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    if len(td) != 2 : continue
    data[td[0].text] = td[1].text.strip()

data_frame = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=data.keys())

data_frame.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(
    "https://thereserve2.apx.com/mymodule/reg/prjView.asp?id1=1295", skiprows=1)[0]

new = pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[:, 4].to_list()], columns=df.iloc[:, 3].to_list())

print(new)

new.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/7b56e1a8a3069c261e8214432ad3e036/data.csv)

[image]